# In Python, is there a string s such that float(s) is None?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm curious. For context, I have a list of string representations of floats (including some None values), and I'd like to use a list comprehension to convert it to a list of actual floats. If the string is 'None', then the code gives an error:

```
arr = ['1', '2.5', 'None']
arr2 = [float(i) for i in arr]
# Gives an error
```

I know that the float function takes inf, -inf, or nan, and I could use those for a workaround, but I'm curious if there's a string that gets cast to None.

Comment: I'm asking because the 'None' values in the input could easily be changed to another string.

Comment: that wouldn't make sense since `None` has it's own type so it wouldn't make much sense for a function that cast's things as floats to convert to a non-float

Comment: To amplify on R Nar's answer — `None` isn't a `float`.  You can see this by typing `float(None)` and getting an error.

Comment: you can, however, use `eval` to get `'None'` to cast to `NoneType` but that would also mean you get `type(eval('1')) == int`

Comment: That makes sense. I'd been thinking of None as a null value, and I'd forgotten that it has its own type. Thanks for clearing this up for me.

Comment: Why not `float(i) if i != 'None' else None`? There's no string for which `float` returns None. In fact, there's no object at all for which `float` returns `None`, even if you try to write such an object yourself.

Comment: moreover `float` and any other "type caster" must return object of  required type or raise an error.

Comment: @RNar: By the way, always remember that `eval()` is dangerous.

Comment: @KevinGuan  yeah I was going to say that, but with such simple strings like these conversions, I figured it wasn't too dangerous

Comment: There is a "not a number" float that you create with `float('nan')`. Change your `None` to `"nan"`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A simple solution would be to use a ternary statement

```
arr2 = [None if i == "None" else float(i) for i in arr]
```